# Highchart Animation on IE7

Tags: highcharts

In IE10 the animation is working perfectly, but when you enable compatibility mode (IE7) the animation simply does not happen.

I'm testing in the demo site of Highcharts: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it looks like a bug so I've reported it in comment here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1711